# Layout Issue GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, gridview

I am using ASP.NET GridView Control to show some data from my SQLDataSource. The final output that I get in Browser is as the following picture.
[image: The GridView Shows the Date in Second column in Second and Fourth Row (Alternate Rows)]

I want the layout to be exactly how it is in Row 1 and 3. I can't figure out why the layout for Rows differ alternatively. I am also attaching my code for the GridView here.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">

    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" SortExpression="BlogPostImage">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("BlogPostImage","~/Uploads/{0}") %>' Width="50px" Height="50px"></asp:Image>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Post Details" SortExpression="BlogPostTitile">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Size="15px" Text='<%# Eval("BlogPostTitile") %>'></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Size="12px" Text='<%# Eval("BlogPostContent").ToString().Length > 50? (Eval("BlogPostContent") as string).Substring(0,50) + "..." : Eval("BlogPostContent")  %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="BlogPostCreationDate">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BlogPostCreationDate", "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Time" SortExpression="BlogPostCreationDate">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BlogPostCreationTime" )%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


    </Columns>

    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />

    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />

</asp:GridView>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like `BlogPostCreationDate` is missing for some of your records...

Comment: Does "BlogPostContent" contain invalid HTML?

Comment: did you check the datasource? it seems values don't correspond to columns in grid

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="BlogPostCreationDate">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BlogPostCreationDate", "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        ***<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Time" SortExpression="**BlogPostCreationTime**">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BlogPostCreationTime" )%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

You should check your sortExpression in your "Time" Header it is BlogPostCreationDate and it should be BlogPostCreationtime.Check it......